# How to keep the $_POST action value from not changing to the ajax page path

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I am using php/jquery/ajax to update a section.  When I execute the ajax call, everything does as it's suppose to.  But the global $_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME] changes to whatever the ajax path is when it returns the requested data back to the page.

I have a page at "clients/index.php";

```php
$str .= "<form action='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]' method='POST'>\n";
// form starts and the action value is set to "clients/index.php"
$str .= "<input type='hidden' name='section' value='thirtyDaySection'>\n";
$str .= "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-sm btn-block btn-success border-dark mb-1' name='action' value='Generate Recurring Invoice'>Generate</button>\n";
$str .= "</form>\n";
// end form

// execute edit/delete functions using bootstrap modal, jquery & ajax
$str .= " <div class='btn-group btn-group-sm p-2' role='group' aria-label='button group'>\n";
$str .= "<button type='button' id='qbinvrecurEditButton' data-cid='$QBIR[clientid]' data-id='$QBIR[QBInvRecurID]' class='btn btn-success btn-sm' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#qbinvrecurEditModal'>Edit</button>\n";
$str .= "<button type='button' id='qbinvrecurDeleteButton' data-cid='$QBIR[clientid]' data-id='$QBIR[QBInvRecurID]' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#qbinvrecurDeleteModal'>Delete</button>\n";
$str .= "<div>\n";
```

JQuery Code

```
$(document).on('click', '#qbinvrecurEditButton', function () {

var id = $(this).data('id');
var cid = $(this).data('cid');
$.ajax({
        url: '../private/ajax/qbinvrecurEdit.php',
        method: 'post',
        data: {
               QBInvRecurID: id, clientid: cid
              },
       success: function (response) {
               $("#qbinvrecurEditForm").html(response);
              }
})
});

$(document).on('click', '#qbinvrecurUpdate', function () {
var BillingDate = $("#ud_BillingDate").val();
var recurring_state = $("#ud_recurring_state").val();
...

$.ajax({
        url: '../private/ajax/qbinvrecurUpdate.php',
        method: 'post',
        data: { BillingDate: BillingDate, recurring_state: recurring_state, 
                QBInvRecurID: QBInvRecurID, RecurType: RecurType, RecurRef: 
                RecurRef, ItemID: ItemID, ItemDesc: ItemDesc, Qty: Qty, Price: 
                Price, Amount: Amount, clientid: clientid, BillingDate: 
                BillingDate, recurring_state: recurring_state, QBInvRecurID: 
                QBInvRecurID, RecurType: RecurType, RecurRef: RecurRef, ItemID: 
                ItemID, ItemDesc: ItemDesc, Qty: Qty, Price: Price, Amount: Amount, 
                clientid: clientid 
             },
             success: function (response) {
                                            $("#content").html(response);
                      }
})
});
```

/* Ajax Code */

```
$sql = "UPDATE `QBInvRecur` SET.... ";
$db_mysqli->query($sql);

echo "Row updated!";

require_once(CLASS_PATH.'/accountingClass.php');
$ac = new accountingClass();

if($_POST["page"] == "clients") {
    require_once(CLASS_PATH . '/customerClass.php');
    $cus = new customerClass();
    $str .= $cus->clientOverview2();
}
 else {
       require_once(CLASS_PATH.'/summaryClass.php');
       $sc = new summaryClass();
       $str .= $sc->getOverview3();
 }
// echo the $str value back to the #content id on the main page.
echo $str;
```

I expect the value of $_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME] to remain "clients/index.php" but it changes all of them to the ajax path.

1. click the "Edit" button triggers the modal to update information.  This sends an ajax request to ../private/ajax/updateRecur.php
2. info updates and on success jquery displays the results on the original page (clients/index.php) however now, that same block looks like this:

```php
$str .= "<form action='/a2kdashboard/private/ajax/updateRecur.php' method='POST'>\n";
// form action value of the same page (clients/index.php) is now set to "/a2kdashboard/private/ajax/updateRecur.php"

$str .= "<input type='hidden' name='clientid' value='$QBIR[clientid]'>\n";
$str .= "<input type='hidden' name='QBInvRecurID' value='$QBIR[QBInvRecurID]'>\n";
$str .= "<input type='hidden' name='section' value='thirtyDaySection'>\n";
$str .= "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-sm btn-block btn-success border-dark mb-1' name='action' value='Generate Recurring Invoice'>Generate</button>\n";
$str .= "</form>\n";
// end form
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]` or `$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]` provides the name path to a current called script which is in your case `/a2kdashboard/private/ajax/updateRecur.php`
if you want something different use directly that path

```
$str .= "<form action='clients/index.php' method='POST'>\n";
```

or else the other option is that pass a current page's name in the request body or query string while making ajax call and use that value as `action`

Comment: OMG - thank you!  So elementary - I guess this is what happens when you overthink your own code!